# MongoDB+php. Можно ли в MongoDB одним запросом и наличие массива в документе проверить и элемент в его вставить?

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$coll_obyav->update(array(
                              'key' => $key
                      ), array(
                              'key' => $key,
                              '$addToSet' => array('obyav' => $info),
                      , array('upsert' => true));
```

Я хочу обновить документ и вставить элементы в массив за одну операцию, но если документа не существует, то выскакивает ошибка т.к. поле массива не определено.
Придется сначало **findOne**ом проверять существует ли документ а затем решать, добавлять новый массив или вставлять элемент в уже существующий массив. Можно ли как то лучше это сделать?